# Error during sbt execution: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: scala, sbt, jce

When I run `sbt` in my project I get the following error:

```
$ sbt
  Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.13 ...
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.<clinit>(JceSecurityManager.java:65)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(Cipher.java:2587)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(Cipher.java:2611)
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isUnlimited(CipherSuite.java:535)
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<init>(CipherSuite.java:507)
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(CipherSuite.java:614)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:294)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.access$100(SSLContextImpl.java:42)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:425)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1634)
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1592)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:122)
at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:332)
at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:289)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:85)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:979)
at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.getURLInfo$57a0216e(BasicURLHandler.java:66)
at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.getURLInfo(BasicURLHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLResource.init(URLResource.java:65)
at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLResource.exists(URLResource.java:81)
at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.findResourceUsingPattern(RepositoryResolver.java:97)
at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.findResourceUsingPatterns(AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.java:96)
at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver.findIvyFileRef(IBiblioResolver.java:102)
at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.getDependency(BasicResolver.java:228)
at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver.getDependency(IBiblioResolver.java:512)
at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver.getDependency(ChainResolver.java:104)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:169)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:714)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:594)
at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:234)
at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:105)
at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:99)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:100)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:350)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$retrieve$1(Launch.scala:208)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$3.apply(Launch.scala:216)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:216)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:196)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:88)
... 78 more
  Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:77)
... 78 more
  Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.loadPolicies(JceSecurity.java:292)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:262)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:48)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:80)
... 80 more
  Error during sbt execution: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Installed on MacOS 10.12.6:

- Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)
- SBT version 0.13.16
- Scala 2.11.11.

Already have tried to clean up everything and reinstall Scala and SBT. but it didn't work for me.

Could you please point me where could be the problem?

Comment: look into "Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty" which may be you are using in your application

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty easy: I just reinstalled JDK8 and cleaned up Ivy cache.